# Do I need to install anything to run Highchart?

Tags: javascript, php, html, highcharts

I am writing a simple program which will print highchart but getting only a blank page.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Highcharts-2.2.2/js/highcharts.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function()var options={chart:{renderTo:'container',type:'spline'},title:{text:'survey data'},subtitle:{text:'from survey form'},
xAxis:{categories:['Jan 2008','Feb 2008','March 2008','April 2008','May 2008'],tickInterval:3},
yAxis:{title:`text:'Percentage %'},min:0
},plotOptions:{series:{lineWidth:2}},series:[{name:'Internet Explorer',data:[54.7,54.7,53.9,54.8,54.4,60.1,64.3,66.1]},{name:'FireFox',data:[36.7,36.1,37.0,39.1,39.8,40.1,43.7]},{name:'Safari',data:[1.9,2.0,2.1,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8]},{
name:'Opera',data:[1.4,1,4,1.4,1.4,1.4,1.5,1.7,1.9]}]});});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am running this as `localhost/folder_name/file_name.php` on XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already set up  the HighChart options but I did not see any initialization code, you might want to put something like this in your code

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Comment: I added 'var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);' but still not working :(

Comment: your jquery ready function looks incorrect : $( document ).ready(function() {
    var options.....   });

Answer (score 1):

You have a few syntax errors with commas / brackets.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'spline'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'survey data'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'from survey form'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan 2008', 'Feb 2008', 'March 2008', 'April 2008', 'May 2008'],
        tickInterval: 3
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          'text': 'Percentage %'
        },
        min: 0
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          lineWidth: 2
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Internet Explorer',
        data: [54.7, 54.7, 53.9, 54.8, 54.4, 60.1, 64.3, 66.1]
      }, {
        name: 'FireFox',
        data: [36.7, 36.1, 37.0, 39.1, 39.8, 40.1, 43.7]
      }, {
        name: 'Safari',
        data: [1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 2.8]
      }, {
        name: 'Opera',
        data: [1.4, 1, 4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9]
      }]
    };

      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
```

Fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/29nm99fo/1/

Comment: no nothing is coming i just pasted your code but still coming blank page. do I have to add any extra file as i am adding highchart.js and jquery.js but dont no why data is not showing. it is really simple but struggling a lot

Comment: solved :D finally script declaration sequence was wrong :D thanks everyone for guiding me